# Identifying cause of exception creating symmetric key in Swift

Tags: xcode, exception, swift, core-foundation

I'm new to Swift/XCode (and I have no Obj-C experience) so I'm working through "toy" exercises, but I can't figure out a debugging issue. Namely, I enabled the breakpoint for all exceptions and now I'm getting a "light" exception (it doesn't terminate execution) which I can't figure out how to diagnose.

As the type of exception isn't shown (and I can't use [this](http://qwan.org/2013/06/18/how-to-snatch-the-error-code-from-the-trap-frame-in-xcode/) Objective C technique to get the information) I'm not sure how to identify what exception is happening.

The code in question:

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = [kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeAES]
let rawcryptokey: [UInt8] = [63, 17, 27, 99, 185, 231, 1, 191,
    217, 74, 141, 16, 12, 99, 253, 41] // (sample)
let cfdatacryptokey: CFDataRef = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, rawcryptokey, rawcryptokey.count)
let cryptokey: SecKeyRef = SecKeyCreateFromData(parameters as CFDictionaryRef,
    cfdatacryptokey, &error).takeRetainedValue()
```

I get Thread1: breakpoint 1.2 but I can continue execution until the "downstream" crash but I don't have a method for determining what exception is being thrown, much less why. While solving the problem with the code is my immediate concern, can anyone suggest a methodology or guide for dealing with exceptions in Swift/CF code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference in how exceptions are used and handled between C++ and Objective-C.

In Objective-C they are intended to be fatal events that indicate pending complete failure.

In C++ they are commonly used in lieu of returning an error value which might not be checked (java and C# use them similarly)  So a network call that fails might throw an exception rather than returning an error value.

Turning on all exceptions will generate a breakpoint even on "normal" C++ exceptions, which are expected and happen with surprising regularity.

My suggestion would be to use "All Objective-C Exceptions", "objc_exception_throw", and "-[NSException raise]"

Comment: Thank you, David: from (distant) past experience, I associated an exception with "Everything is on fire" as opposed to what appears to be "Less than ideal situation here." Still, it's odd that there isn't a cleaner way to identify exactly isn't working perfectly.

Comment: Well, in the non-objective-c case, exceptions may be used to handle normal error returns.  It's particularly valuable in the case of functions that don't have a clearly definable error return value.